# Post call from JS doesn't send data to the backend

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

Trying to send login data from my front end to mongodb.

So my js file takes the id and pass values from the pug file and does a post call, which sends the login id and pass.

The route /postlist then takes the value and renders it.

The error I'm getting is that no values are being passed to the ajax call, even tho the values of id and pass show up when I do console.log

This is my pug file

```
script(type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js")
script( type= 'text/javascript',src='/javascripts/script.js')


form( id='formSignIn')
    div.form-group
      label(for='name') Id:
      input#name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='id' name='name')
    div.form-group
      label(for='pw') Password:
      input#password.form-control(type='password', name='password')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', id='submit') Sign In
```

this is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("hi");

    var name,password;
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        id= $("#name").val();
        // console.log("/////////",name);
        pass=$("#password").val();
        console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$", id, pass)
        $.post("/signup", {name: id, password: pass} ,function(data){
         alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        }).fail(function(){
      console.log("error");

        // console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
        localStorage.setItem('user',id);
        });
})})
```

this is my code in router/index.js(Using express for this project)

```
router.post('/login', function(req,res){
console.log("fhfdghd")
 var db = req.db;
    // Set our collection
   var userCollection = db.collection('user');
    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    console.log("BODY", req.body)
    var id = req.body.name;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var query = {"id": id, "password": password}
     db.collection('user').findOne(query, function(err, user){
      if(err) {throw new Error(err);}
      else if(!user){ 
        console.log('Not found');
    }
      else{ 

        sses=req.session;
        sses.user=req.body.name;

        console.log('Found!');
        res.end('done');
        res.redirect('/');
        }
  })
});
```

Comment: where its not passing?? In your `$(document).ready` it's printing??

Comment: yes the js file is successfully linked. The problem is in my js file when I do the Post call, the values don't get passed. You can check it out yourself https://github.com/BigDaddy-Zephyr/Hacker-news

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://github.com/BigDaddy-Zephyr/Hacker-news) You are not using body-parser nodejs requires body parser for getting body data on backend so you have to install and use it in your app.js like this

**Step1:**

```
npm i body-parser
```

**Step2:**
Require in app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

**Step3:**
Use it like this

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
//   extended: true
// }));
```

After this you should get your data.

Comment: Okay tried it after installing didn't work. Am I doing it right? https://github.com/BigDaddy-Zephyr/Hacker-news

Comment: you have to do bodyparser instead of express in app.use. here `app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
`